# Is there a more efficient way to extract a subset of an array with indexes that depend on a list?

Tags: f#, subset

I wrote a function that returns a subset of an array (as a list) that consists of the elements whose indexes are equal to `(n + some index of another list)`.

An array was used instead of a list for efficiency, but a list could have been used with the same effect.

My tests show the function works fine. But I wonder if there is a faster way to do this, as the function looks a bit cumbersome to me.

So here is the function:

```
let shiftFrom (n: int) (xs: 'T list) (arr: 'T []) : 'T list =
        let len = arr.Length - 1
        let rec loop (acc: 'T list) (zs: list<int>*list<'T>) =
            match zs with
            | [], _ -> acc
            | _, [] -> acc
            | (i::is), (w::ws) ->
                if i + n > len then acc
                elif w = arr.[i] then  loop (arr.[i+n]::acc) (is, ws)
                else loop acc (is, w::ws)  
        loop [] ([0..len], xs)
        |> List.rev
```

The function passed this test:

```
let arr = [0..10] |> Array.ofList
let xs = [0; 2; 5; 7; 9]
shiftFrom 2 xs arr
// val it : int list = [2; 4; 7; 9]
```

Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

(For this specific example there is an obvious one, my question relates to the general case where `arr` is not so nice).

Comment: Re: `Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?` Do you have issue with the speed of the execution (in which case some benchmark timings would be helpful) or the complexity of the code?

Comment: Can you clarify what the `elif w = arr.[i] then ...` is supposed to do? It's really unclear what your function is supposed to do. I suggest to provide an example with strings as elements. It's hella confusing that your elements are of the same type as the indeces.

Comment: Is `xs` guaranteed to be a subset of `arr`? Are there elements in `xs` that are not part of `arr`?

Comment: @s952163 - Both, see my comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that `xs` is a subset of `arr`:

```
xs 
|> List.choose (fun x -> Array.tryFindIndex ((=) x) arr)
|> List.choose (fun x -> Array.tryItem (x+n) arr)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I tested the speed with `n = 3`, `xs = [0.0..3.0..100000.0]` and `arr = [0.0..100000.0] |> Array.ofList`. Your solution was 2500 times faster than my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
let shiftFrom (n: int) (xs: int list) (arr: 'T []) : 'T list =
    xs |> List.choose (fun i -> arr |> Array.tryItem (i + n))
```

Comment: Your function does something quite different from mine. Notice for example `elif w = arr.[i]` in my code and that my `xs` is not a list of `ints`, but is a list of `'T` like `arr` is an array of `'T`.